# Best puma config for local development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, process, puma

#### Question

What is the ideal puma config in development mode for optimizing performance?

#### Background

Our rails app runs annoyingly slow in development mode; the server will frequently freeze up and have to be manually terminated using `kill -9 [process number]`, and refreshing the app in the browser on code change can take a long time. We are a json api on rails 6 using puma, and our puma config is as follows. We also use [active_admin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin), which I mention because it is the only part of our app that really uses the asset pipeline and is the slowest part of our app to do development on (refreshing admin app after code change takes the longest).

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch('RAILS_MAX_THREADS') { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count

# Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests; default is 3000.
#
port        ENV.fetch('PORT') { 3000 }

# Specifies the `environment` that Puma will run in.
#
environment ENV.fetch('RAILS_ENV') { 'development' }
```

We have done `puma -w 5` to increase the number of workers, which in theory should increase throughput and the potential number of db connections (correct me if this is wrong), but it hasn't had a noticeable impact on performance of the app. From what I've read doing `puma -w 5` is also not a great idea during development because it means every time you change some code each worker has to reload the entire app, which would mean it is better to just run one worker locally so the app only has to reload one time on code change. It's possible that this slowness does not have to do with our puma config and that it is perhaps another issue, but regardless I would love to hear thoughts on how to best configure puma to run optimally in development mode.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Did you investigate why exactly your application is slow in development? Is it slow in other environments too? What causes it to be slow? The number of API requests? Slow database queries? Not enough memory on your development machine?

Comment: Good questions. It is not slow in other environments. I don't think it's an issue with my machine, as I have 32BG of ram. We've been good about optimizing our queries so things are looking good in that area. it could be the number of api requests happening at once, as there are quite a few when a user enters the app, but I'm not sure we should change that since it runs well in other environments. Are you thinking tweaking the puma config is probably the wrong way to address the issue?